# EDITGetting error main() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, django, google-ads-api

I am testing out google adwords api features (NOTE: This question isn't directly aimed at Google Ad Words API).

I am facing an error that says: main() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Heres what I have done:

1) Created a Keyword model that has a keyword Charfield

2) Created a KeywordForm that has a form element of type CharField

3) Used the form in a HTML page to get the keyword through the POST method

4) After the POST, the URL is routed to a view keyword_add which sets two values namely

```
adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()
ad_group_id = 'XXXXXXXXX`
```

Also, it gets the value of keyword model using

```
new_keyword = Keyword.objects.all()
```

It then calls a function located in a python script using the function call

```
    ad_group_update.main(adwords_client, ad_group_id, new_keyword)
```

5) The function main in the python script add_keywords is executed using the three arguments adwords_client, ad_group_id & new_keyword

The following error arises when I do this :

1) [error while executing main()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0fMc.png)

Apart from this error, I have another question in the code:

```
from googleads import adwords


AD_GROUP_ID = 'INSERT_AD_GROUP_ID_HERE'


def main(client, ad_group_id, keyword):
  # Initialize appropriate service.
  ad_group_criterion_service = client.GetService(
      'AdGroupCriterionService', version='v201710')

  # Construct keyword ad group criterion object.
  keyword1 = {
      'xsi_type': 'BiddableAdGroupCriterion',
      'adGroupId': ad_group_id,
      'criterion': {
          'xsi_type': 'Keyword',
          'matchType': 'BROAD',
          'text': 'MARS'
      },
      # These fields are optional.
      'userStatus': 'PAUSED',
      'finalUrls': {
          'urls': ['http://example.com/keyword']
      }
  }

  keyword2 = {
      'xsi_type': 'NegativeAdGroupCriterion',
      'adGroupId': ad_group_id,
      'criterion': {
          'xsi_type': 'Keyword',
          'matchType': 'EXACT',
          'text': 'pluto'
      }
  }

  # Construct operations and add ad group criteria.
  operations = [
      {
          'operator': 'ADD',
          'operand': keyword1
      },
      {
          'operator': 'ADD',
          'operand': keyword2
      }
  ]
  ad_group_criteria = ad_group_criterion_service.mutate(
      operations)['value']

  # Display results.
  for criterion in ad_group_criteria:
    print(('Keyword ad group criterion with ad group id "%s", criterion id '
           '"%s", text "%s", and match type "%s" was added.'
           % (criterion['adGroupId'], criterion['criterion']['id'],
              criterion['criterion']['text'],
              criterion['criterion']['matchType'])))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Initialize client object.
  adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()
  main(adwords_client, AD_GROUP_ID, )
```

How do I use the argument new_keyword to update the text element of Keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
# Initialize client object.
    adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()
    main(adwords_client, AD_GROUP_ID, )
```

you are passing 2 arguments but `def main(__, __, __)` takes 3 arguments.

```
main(adwords_client, AD_GROUP_ID, )
```

that's why you are getting error.